# When is the best period to fix a door frame?

Tags: door-frame

When we moved in our condo, one of the doors had issues closing correctly so we decided to fix it during last autumn. We made it to close perfectly.

It seems the house has moved *a lot* during this last winter, and now it no longer closes correctly, as if the frame had sheared (the wall at a corner of the door has even cracked).

Now I'd like to fix it correctly (again) once and for all. Taking into consideration that the house moves, *I'm wondering **when** would be the best time of the year to fix it* so that it always closes correctly all year-round? When is a house is it's 'most-average-position'?

Maybe-not-so-important-facts:

- The unit is located in the province of Quebec.
- The building is about 15-16 years old.
- We're occupying the 2nd and 3rd floors of a condo block.
- We have a concrete slab that separate us from the owner of the unit on the 1st floor.
- We have a brick wall that separates us from the owner that live on the same floor.
- The unit has been owned by family since its construction, so we know for sure that the wall at that location has never cracked before.

Answer (score 1):

Well the big thing you're going to notice is just humidity will change it a lot.  If you want a door that closes properly year round, then the best time would be when it is not too humid, or not too dry (i.e spring would be fine).  This way when it gets humid or dry, you minimize the amount of warping the frame goes through

Comment: Yeah, right now is kind of the most dry season and we're getting out of the really cold part of the year, maybe I'll way a month or so..! Thanks for your input!

Comment: I would wait a little later in the season still, after the heating season is over by a month or so. If you shave the door down, get the gap so a coin will fit cleanly around the perimeter. Make sure while trimming you keep the bevel (3 degree, no more!! or no more than an 1/8" using a square) on the knob side of the door. I usually bevel the top a little too.